# How can I solve finding consecutive factors problem in an optimal way?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to develop a function which finds consecutive factors of the given number and then the function will return the smallest of these consecutive numbers.

I tried to solve a Codility question. (I submitted my solution)
I need to develop the solution function.

def solution(N):
   # write your code in Python 3.6
   pass

An example:
If N is 6, the function will return 2 (because of 6 = 2 * 3)
If N is 20, the function will return 4 (because of 20 = 4 * 5)
If N is 29, the function will return 0

I developed the solution function (by checking all the numbers from 1 up to N, brute force search) and it works.
However, when the argument of the solution function is too big, the execution of the function takes too much time. Codility Python engine is running the function for a while and then it is throwing TIMEOUT ERROR.

What may be an optimal solution for this problem?

Thank you

I developed the function but it is not optimized.

```py
def solution(N):
   for i in range(1,N+1):
      if i * (i+1) == N:
         return i
   return 0
```

When N is too big like 12,567,543, the function execution takes too much time.

Comment: I think any consecutive factors will be on opposite sides of the square root of the number. i.e. one number will be less than the square root, and the other will be greater than the square root. Since you are looking for consecutive numbers, I think you only need to check the floor of the square root * the ceiling of the square root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my comment, I thought a little bit about the question.

If you have an integer, `N`, and two consecutive factors, `m` and `m+1`, then it MUST be true that `m < sqrt(N)` and `m + 1 > sqrt(N)`

Therefore, all you have to do is check if the floor of the square root times the ceiling of the square root is equal to your original number..

```
import math
def solution(N):
    n1 = math.floor(math.sqrt(N))
    n2 = n1 + 1 # or n2 = math.ceil(math.sqrt(N))
    if n1*n2 == N:
        return n1
    return 0
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I looked for.

Comment: Good one. That's some "maths".

Answer (score 0):

This has a run time of O(1).

```
import math
import math
def mysol(n):
    s = math.sqrt(n)

    if math.floor(s) * math.ceil(s) == n:
        return math.floor(s)

    else:
        return 0
```